# Ruby (Rails) gsub: pass the captured string into a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to match a string as such:

```
text = "This is a #hastag"
raw(
  h(text).gsub(/(?:\B#)(\w*[A-Z]+\w*)/i, embed_hashtag('\1'))
)

def embed_hashtag('data')
  #... some code to turn the captured hashtag string into a link
  #... return the variable that includes the final string
end
```

My problem is that when I pass `'\1'` in my embed_hashtag method that I call with gsub, it simply passes `"\1"` literally, rather than the first captured group from my regex. Is there an alternative?

FYI:

1. I'm wrapping text in `h` to escape strings, but then I'm embedding code into user inputted text (i.e. hashtags) which needs to be passed raw (hence `raw`).
2. It's important to keep the "#" symbol apart from the text, which is why I believe I need the capture group.
3. If you have a better way of doing this, don't hesitate to let me know, but I'd still like an answer for the sake of answering the question in case someone else has this question.

Comment: You need to use *block* version of `#gsub`.. Not the one you are using.. This [discussion](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4457150) will help you to understand this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use the block form `gsub(regex){ $1 }` instead of `gsub(regex, '\1')`
- You can simplify the regex to `/\B#(\w+)/i` as well
- You can leave out the `h()` helper, Rails 4 will escape malicious input by default
- Specify method arguments as `embed_hashtag(data)` instead of `embed_hashtag('data')`
- You need to define `embed_hashtag` before doing the substitution
- To build a link, you can use `link_to(text, url)`

This should do the trick:

```
def embed_hashtag(tag)
  url = 'http://example.com'
  link_to tag, url
end

raw(
  text.gsub(/\B#(\w+)/i){ embed_hashtag($1) }
)
```

Comment: For the alternative form, `embed_hashtag` must receive `x[1]` as parameter.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sorry, you're (almost) right. The second form does not work, but yours does not work either because it means "first character of entire match". So the only solution is to use `$1`

Comment: and there is no way to pass the first capturing group to the function?

Comment: Yes, there is – it is the solution I posted. `$&` contains the whole last match; `$1` ... `$9` contain capture groups 1 ... 9 of last match; `$~` contains `MatchData` object and is equivalent to `Regexp.last_match`. Refer to the documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be the use of a block here.

**Example**:

```
def embed_hashtag(data)
  puts "#{data}"
end

text = 'This is a #hashtag'
raw(
 h(text).gsub(/\B#(\S+)/) { embed_hashtag($1) }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try last match regexp shortcut:

```
=> 'zzzdzz'.gsub(/d/) { puts $~[0] }
=> 'd'
=> "zzzzz"
```